# Showing multiple simultaneous tool tips in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, tooltip

I want to add a feature to my Mac app inspired by the Help mode in iPhoto for iPad, pictured below. I would love to do this using built-in APIs, so I don't have to build my own tool-tip-like view. Is there any way for me to either show multiple tool tips at the same time, or to achieve something similar using `NSHelpManager`?

[image: iPhoto Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting 10.7 or later you could do this fairly easily using `NSPopover`.  You would have to create quite a few popover windows but it isn't difficult to do.

Comment: Yeah, I am targeting Lion. I hadn't thought of a popover, thanks for the suggestion. I suppose I was looking for something a little lighter-weight, but that might work. Maybe I'll make a subclass that just contains a text field.